# Enhance sensivity of my magnetic field measuring setup

Tags: oscilloscope, magnetics, electromagnetic, probe, spectrum-analyzer

I have the following magnetic field measuring setup:

- Picoscope 2204A
- 16m wounded up bell wire connected to tip and ground clip as search coil antenna

Now I want to enhance the sensivity for 50Hz to 1MHz.

I have thought about the following things:

- Picoscope measuring sensivity is near white noise, so an osciloscope amplifier wouldn't have an effect I think.
- Maybe replace the bell wire with a litz wire with many strands like in Coaxial cables? RG58?

Comment: You didn't mention the magnetic field source you are trying to detect.

Comment: I measure All sort of consumer electronics like notebooks, powerbanks, smartphones...

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: Send back the electronics with too much emission to preserve my nerves.